# Problema con funcion para sumar cartas

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tengo este componente en React, para simular un juego de Blackjack, mi problema es que no puedo hacer correctamente la funcionabilidad para que el Croupier robe cartas. Cuando se pasa de 21 o llega a un valor mayor de 16, el funcionamiento no es el deseado. A ver si alguien descubre donde tengo mi error. El codigo de la funcion es el siguiente:

En principio hace bien la logica de agregar cartas hasta que la suma cumple la condicion, pero por alguna razon, pareciera que vuelve a hacer la llamada recursiva que existe dentro de la funcion, y no estaria encontrando donde

```
const [playerCards, setPlayerCards] = useState([
    generateRandomCard(),
    generateRandomCard(),
  ]);
  const [croupierCards, setCroupierCards] = useState([generateRandomCard()]);
  const [cardsSum, setCardsSum] = useState(
    playerCards.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
  );
  const [croupierSum, setCroupierSum] = useState(
    croupierCards.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
  );
  const [currentBet, setCurrentBet] = useState(10);
  const [chips, setChips] = useState(1000);
  const [result, setResult] = useState();
  const [isCroupierTakingCards, setIsCroupierTakingCards] = useState(false);
  const handleCroupierTurn = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("el croupier roba una carta", isCroupierTakingCards);
    if (croupierSum < 17) {
      // Si la puntuación del croupier es menor que 17, toma una nueva carta
      console.log("llamada recursiva", croupierCards);
      const randomCard = generateRandomCard();

      // Utiliza la función de actualización para agregar la nueva carta al estado anterior
      setCroupierCards((prevCroupierCards) => [
        ...prevCroupierCards,
        randomCard,
      ]);

      console.log(croupierCards);

      // Calcula la suma después de actualizar croupierCards
      const sumCroupier = [...croupierCards, randomCard].reduce(
        (a, b) => a + b,
        0
      );

      // Actualiza croupierSum
      setCroupierSum(sumCroupier);
      console.log("suma local", sumCroupier);
      console.log("suma state", croupierSum);

      // Llama a la función de forma recursiva para seguir tomando cartas si es necesario
      if (isCroupierTakingCards) {
        if (sumCroupier < 17) {
          console.log("debo llamar nuevamente a la funcion");
          setTimeout(handleCroupierTurn, 1000); // Agrega un pequeño retraso para dar efecto de toma de cartas
        } else {
          setIsCroupierTakingCards(false); // Detiene la toma de cartas del croupier
        }
      } else {
        setIsCroupierTakingCards(false); // Detiene la toma de cartas del croupier
      }
      console.log(
        "isCroupierTakingCards en el final de la funcion",
        isCroupierTakingCards
      );
    }
  }, [
    croupierSum,
    croupierCards,
    setCroupierCards,
    setIsCroupierTakingCards,
    isCroupierTakingCards,
  ]);

  const handleStand = () => {
    // Ejecutar la lógica del croupier después de que el jugador presione "Stand"
    setIsCroupierTakingCards(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Ejecuta la lógica del croupier después de que el jugador presiona "Stand"
    if (isCroupierTakingCards) {
      handleCroupierTurn();
    }
  }, [isCroupierTakingCards, handleCroupierTurn]);
```